# Error When trying to inherit TabControl

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys i got the following error when trying to inherit tabcontrol: Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' Specified for class 'Form1' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' of one of its other partial types!

Here is a picture: http://prntscr.com/3dqzd6

What im trying to make is a animated tab control. i Found a code but it was only for visual basic(I code in c# but this code was for vb only)
My code:

```
Public Class Form1
Inherits TabControl//Here i got the error
Dim OldIndex As Integer

Private _Speed As Integer = 9
Property Speed As Integer
    Get
        Return _Speed
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If value > 20 Or value < -20 Then
            MsgBox("Speed needs to be in between -20 and 20.")
        Else
            _Speed = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Sub New()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
End Sub

Sub DoAnimationScrollLeft(ByVal Control1 As Control, ByVal Control2 As Control)
    Dim G As Graphics = Control1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim P1 As New Bitmap(Control1.Width, Control1.Height)
    Dim P2 As New Bitmap(Control2.Width, Control2.Height)
    Control1.DrawToBitmap(P1, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
    Control2.DrawToBitmap(P2, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))

    For Each c As Control In Control1.Controls
        c.Hide()
    Next

    Dim Slide As Integer = Control1.Width - (Control1.Width Mod _Speed)

    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 0 To Slide Step _Speed
        G.DrawImage(P1, New Rectangle(a, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
        G.DrawImage(P2, New Rectangle(a - Control2.Width, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))
    Next
    a = Control1.Width
    G.DrawImage(P1, New Rectangle(a, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
    G.DrawImage(P2, New Rectangle(a - Control2.Width, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))

    SelectedTab = Control2

    For Each c As Control In Control2.Controls
        c.Show()
    Next

    For Each c As Control In Control1.Controls
        c.Show()
    Next
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnSelecting(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs)
    If OldIndex < e.TabPageIndex Then
        DoAnimationScrollRight(TabPages(OldIndex), TabPages(e.TabPageIndex))
    Else
        DoAnimationScrollLeft(TabPages(OldIndex), TabPages(e.TabPageIndex))
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDeselecting(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs)
    OldIndex = e.TabPageIndex
End Sub

Sub DoAnimationScrollRight(ByVal Control1 As Control, ByVal Control2 As Control)
    Dim G As Graphics = Control1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim P1 As New Bitmap(Control1.Width, Control1.Height)
    Dim P2 As New Bitmap(Control2.Width, Control2.Height)
    Control1.DrawToBitmap(P1, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
    Control2.DrawToBitmap(P2, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))

    For Each c As Control In Control1.Controls
        c.Hide()
    Next

    Dim Slide As Integer = Control1.Width - (Control1.Width Mod _Speed)

    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 0 To -Slide Step -_Speed
        G.DrawImage(P1, New Rectangle(a, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
        G.DrawImage(P2, New Rectangle(a + Control2.Width, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))
    Next
    a = Control1.Width
    G.DrawImage(P1, New Rectangle(a, 0, Control1.Width, Control1.Height))
    G.DrawImage(P2, New Rectangle(a + Control2.Width, 0, Control2.Width, Control2.Height))

    SelectedTab = Control2

    For Each c As Control In Control2.Controls
        c.Show()
    Next

    For Each c As Control In Control1.Controls
        c.Show()
    Next
End Sub
```

Please help me!

-Christos

Comment: You must have a form named form1. Change the name of this class.

Comment: What you mean? Can you give me a example?

Comment: Names like "Form1" are auto-generated for a good reason.  It is supposed to help you keep you of trouble.  Didn't work, hard to guess how your brain got mis-wired so badly.  Surely it was not because you ever picked up a book about Winforms or Visual Studio.  You have to press the B button on the controller to make that jump, use Project + Add New Item + Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a form the designer makes one named `Form1` it has a `Partial Class` by the same name - this is where the generated code is maintained and should not be touched by you. This `Form1` Inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and hence cannot be made to inherit from a `TabControl`. If you simply change the name of the class you have above that intends to be a `Sub-Classed` version of the `TabControl` then all would be well.

```
Public Class Form1
 ...
End Class

Partial Class Form1
 'same class as above just allowed to be seperate
 'they share the internal code
End Class
```

Your code should start like:

```
Public Class myTabControl : Inherits TabControl
 'continue with sub classing
```